# I get an error movies.add is not a function, shouldn't this be working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
class MovieCollection extends Array {
    constructor(name, ...items){ // using rest to get all other items 
        super(...items);  // using spread to make them into array
        this.name = name;  /* assigning name  */
    }
    //method to add new movie to the array
    add(movie){
        this.push(movie);
    }
}

const movies = new MovieCollection("col1",
    {
        title: "hello",
        rating: 10
    },
    {
        title: "hello3",
        rating:40
    }
);

movies.add("asas");

console.log(movies);
```

I'm extending Arrays to add items. Basically `new Array();`
Don't know why this code is not working. This might be a bad practice but doing this just to learn.

Error seems to be on add function.

Comment: That exact code is working fine in Chrome 62.

Comment: Working in firefox 55.0.3

Comment: @ngpmk Are you transpiling the code with Babel? If so, include more info on your babel and build configuration.

Comment: I tried this on es6console.com it's not working.

Comment: Thanks working fine on new Firefox quantum developer edition.